# How to set up servername.local in Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, hostname

I'm trying to set up an Ubuntu server with a fixed IP address. I've set up a reserved ID in my firewall and that works - the server uses DHCP to retrieve the 192.168.1.200 IP address fine. However, when I installed full Ubuntu I can ping servername.local from anywhere on the LAN and it works but not with Ubuntu Server installed? Pinging 192.168.1.200 works fine so how can servername.local be resolved?

Comment: Have you checked the avahi-daemon.service is running on the server? You might need to install it

Comment: Thx. avahi was not running. I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Thx to @PonJar above. Yes avahi was not installed. Fix:

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y avahi-daemon
```